# Angularjs - WYSIWYG image resize manually

Tags: angularjs, wysiwyg

How i want to resize image inside WYSIWYG editor when user upload image? I manage to insert into editor but i cant resize the image.

Below is my code :

http://embed.plnkr.co/yxMbI54wYUlxu2hSpfw8/preview

Appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch clicks on images inserted to the textarea and prompt for new size. The code below is **only conceptual**:

```
$(textarea[0]).on("click", "img", function(){
   var me = this,
       size = prompt("Size: ", me.width + "x" + me.height);
   if (size) {
       scope.$apply(function(){
           var [w,h] = size.split("x");
           $(me).css({ width: w, height: h });
       });
   }
});
```

Insert this snippet into `link` function of the `wysiwyg` directive, insert an image and click on it.

Notice that you cannot use standard `angular.element` because it doesn't support selectors in the `.on` method, so you **have to use** ol'good jQuery instead.

[plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/hS50jpTZCN5NXhwCZZhW/)

Comment: Thank you Andrejs..  your solution seems good. But i would like to resize image directly by drag the image corner. Something like this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593077/how-to-resize-the-image-by-dragging but i failed to integrate with my plunkr.